# Can HTMLInput name take the values like arrays

Tags: html, input

This is an old doubt of mine which surfaced again today.
Coming from an ASP.NET background I was surprised to see this snippet

```
<input name='text[en]' value='aaaaaa' />
```

It was the first time I am seeing an array like value given for `name`
I know that this code runs.

My doubts are,

1. Is this markup valid?
2. What all values are supported for `name`?
3. Where can I see a W3C specification on this?

Comment: It's very common to do it this way. Have seen it a lot of times and gotta admit, that I did it also, but not so often. I don't think that there is a restriction in the w3c specification on this. It only tells you whicht attributes you can use, but not what they may contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Yes, it's possible.

2 - Name is type CDATA:

> CDATA
>
> Attribute values of type CDATA are made up of a sequence of characters
>   that may include entities. Line feeds are ignored while each carriage
>   return and tab is replaced with a space. Browsers may ignore leading
>   and trailing whitespace within the attribute value.
>
> CDATA attribute values are typically case-sensitive, though this is
>   not the case with all attributes that take CDATA values.

3 - Maybe this help: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4

Answer (score 2):

this html is not valid

please refer to w3c html spec below:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

src: section 6.2 of http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html

"[" and "]" are not allowed in value of "NAME" attribute.

and, asp.net doesn't support this, though some php code can do this.

Comment: @naveen: yes, ignoring rules for convenience. not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Yes is the answer but it's only the string.

You can use `<input name="test[]" />`

and you will receive an array of all inputs with name "test[]" in an array with name "test"

You can read for all this in 
[here](http://www.razzed.com/2009/01/30/valid-characters-in-attribute-names-in-htmlxml/)